# Void and Cancel via backend for Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

Situation:
Client made an order, and choose Authorize.net as payment method
Within 24 hours he want to cancel it
Authorize.net has not yet settled the payment, and Cancel action from backend returns an error message
My task:
Create a void action
Problem:
As code investigation shows - default authorize.net payment method for magento have the same method for cancel and void. To be exact - cancel action refers to void action.
Question:
How to achieve void for payment in this situation, which will not return an error?

Comment: which error throw while you trying to cancel ?

Comment: @KeyurShah The referenced transaction does not meet the criteria for issuing a credit. (ID: 54)

Comment: Have you checked your capture amount has been settled or not ? By logging into your Authorize.net control panel

Comment: @KeyurShah It was not settled, as I said.